React build error - Development server runs fine
I am getting the most frustrating error when trying to build my react app.
I can run the development server fine, and there is no more information into what is wrong here. Any help or if you want more information let me know


react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build... One of your dependencies,
babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any
time.
babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will ever
be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this
message go away.    Failed to compile.
Attempted import error: 'React' is not exported from 'react' (imported
as 'React').

Here is my package.json file.
I have already tried a delete of my node_modules folder and a fresh npm install, I get the same result
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.18.6",
    "@rjsf/core": "^5.18.1",
    "@rjsf/mui": "^5.15.1",
    "@rjsf/utils": "^5.18.1",
    "@rjsf/validator-ajv6": "^5.18.1",
    "@rjsf/validator-ajv8": "^5.15.1",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.5.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.0.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^4.0.12",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1",
    "react-router-guards": "^1.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.1",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


Try import * as React from 'react'

I am struggling to see how this might fix the issue with the build considering it compiles with the development server could you explain ?

More info: import * as React from 'react'; vs import React from 'react';

I have tried this on all the imports that I can control in my app and yet still the same result

Can you edit your question and add your package.json as well? This is happening because babel is transforming a package that might not be supported by some other dependency. But I would try the usual suspects like deleting node_modules and doing a fresh npm i
